# AngularJS throws exception when trying to saveChanges with breeze

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I'm new to AngularJS and Breeze. I'm trying to save changes and have a problem with that. Here's my code:

In controller:

```
function update() {
        vm.loading = true;
        return datacontext.saveSettings().then(function () {
            vm.loading = false; // never gets called
        }).fail(function (data) {
            vm.loading = false; // never gets called
        });
    }
```

In datacontext:

```
 function saveSettings() {
        if (manager.hasChanges()) {
            manager.saveChanges() // breaks here if there are changes
                .then(saveSucceeded)
                .fail(saveFailed)
                .catch(saveFailed);
        } else {
            log("Nothing to save");
            return false;
        };
    }
```

The error is thrown in `angular.js` and it's very unhelpful `TypeError: undefined is not a function` I guess there is something simple I'm missing here, but can't figure out what is it.

Want to note that it does send correct data to SaveChanges method on server, but the error is thrown before any response from the server received. After the response is received it throws another error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` but it might be related to the fact the response I return is invalid. I haven't got to that part yet.

Can anyone anyone help with it? I'm lost here.

UPDATE

Here is how I construct my dataservice and manager:

```
var serviceName = "http://admin.localhost:33333/api/breeze/"; // 
var ds = new breeze.DataService({
    serviceName: serviceName,
    hasServerMetadata: false,
    useJsonp: true,
    jsonResultsAdapter: jsonResultsAdapter
});
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: ds });
model.initialize(manager.metadataStore);
```

Comment: @Kiee not sure what you mean by that? I try to follow the Hot Towel application example and contructed my datacontext similar to that. All the get data methods work fine so the datacontext works, I updated the question to include the way I create the manager.

Comment: I am not much sure but you can't use `then` function if `datacontext.saveSettings()` does not return promise in update function.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya the code is taken from here http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/save-changes , any idea how do I return a promise and what should it contain?

Comment: hi,did you fetch the metadata????

Comment: @parthicool05 no, I don't have server metadata as I'm not using Entity Framework. I built my models manually on the client and I suspect the problem might be there, although as I said before get data and bindings work fine.

Comment: Is there any stack track that you can get from the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Your `datacontext` method does not return a promise so the caller cannot find anything to hang the `then` or `fail` call on.
2. You should be calling`catch`, not `fail`

### 1. Return a promise

Your `saveSettings` method did not return a result in the success case so it must fail. Your method must also return a promise in the fail case ... or it will also fail.

And while I'm here, since there is no real difference between your success and fail case, you might as well move the `vm.loading` toggle to the `finally` clause.

Try this instead:

```
function update() {
    vm.loading = true;
    return datacontext.saveSettings()
        .then(function () {
            // .. success handling if you have any
        })
        .catch(function (data) {
            // .. fail handling if you have any
        })
        .finally(funtion() {
            vm.loading = false; // turn it off regardless
        });
}
```

And now the `dataContext` ... notice the two `return` statements return a promise.

```
function saveSettings() {
    if (manager.hasChanges()) {
        return manager.saveChanges() 
            .then(saveSucceeded)
            .catch(saveFailed);
    } else {
        log("Nothing to save");
        // WHY ARE YOU FAILING WHEN THERE IS NOTHING TO SAVE? 
        // Breeze will handle this gracefully without your help
        return breeze.Q.reject(new Error('Nothing to save'));
    };
}
```

### 2. Use *catch*

I assume you have configured Breeze to use Angular's `$q` for promises (you should be using the "breeze.angular" service and have injected "breeze" somewhere).

[`$q` does not have a `fail` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)!  The equivalent is `catch`. For some reason you have both attached to your query. You'll get the `ReferenceError` exception immediately, before the server has a chance to respond ... although it will launch the request and you will get a callback from the server too.

Try just:

```
return manager.saveChanges() 
    .then(saveSucceeded)
    .catch(saveFailed);
```

You see many Breeze examples that call `fail` and `fin`. These are "Q.js" methods; "Q.js" is an alternative promise library - one used by Breeze/KnockOut apps and it was the basis for Angular's `$q`.

Both "Q.js" and `$q` support the now-standard `catch` and `finally` promise methods. We're slowly migrating our example code to this standard. There is a lot of old `fail`/`finally` code around in different venues. It will take time.

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Update `savesetting` function like below to return `Promise`.

```
function saveSettings() {
    if (manager.hasChanges()) {
       return manager.saveChanges(); // return promise

    } else {
        log("Nothing to save");
        return false;
    };
}
```

Then you can call then and fail in update function like following.

```
function update() {
    vm.loading = true;
    return datacontext.saveSettings().then(function () {
        vm.loading = false; // never gets called
    }).fail(function (data) {
        vm.loading = false; // never gets called
    });
}
```

Comment: See my comment on `catch` vs. `fail`