# Breeze save bundle format

Tags: breeze, openedge

I am using Breeze JS and would like to implement a server with full CRUD functionality using Progress Openedge. The Breeze website talks a lot about being able to write your own server implementation but I can find no information describing the format of a save bundle that Breeze sends to the server. Does anyone know of any documentation or schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SaveBundle` is not documented for a very good reason: **it has no definition in BreezeJS!**

It could be **any serialized object that your server requires** to satisfy your`saveChanges` work flow. You can see that this is true by examining the [*a60_abstractDataServiceAdapter.js* source](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/master/src/a60_abstractDataServiceAdapter.js#L143) in github:

```
proto._prepareSaveBundle = function (/*saveContext, saveBundle*/) {
  ...
  throw new Error("Need a concrete implementation of _prepareSaveBundle");
};
```

Breeze *does ship* with an implementation [*b00_breeze.dataService.webApi*](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/master/src/b00_breeze.dataService.webApi.js#L23) that satisfies the expectations of the companion Breeze ASP.NET Web API helper classes such as [`ContextProvider`](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/master/Breeze.ContextProvider/ContextProvider.cs). This implementation is worth studying if you decide to write your own server support code.

But it is only one of *many possible implementations*. An OData web server, for example, requires an entirely different package and format for "$batch" change-set saves. Only you know what's right for your "Progress Openedge" server.

All that said, we do delve into some critical aspects of the `SaveBundle` destined for Breeze Web API services in the [documentation for "ContextProvider"](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/contextprovider).

Feel free to follow-up with more specific questions after you've read that.

Comment: Thanks Ward, that has cleared up a lot of things. To be clearer in my original question - I am writing my own server implementation from scratch by unpicking the JSON. I guess that I could write my own JSON serializer on the client, but was intending on using your Web API serializer as it seems to do the job just fine even though I am not using Web API on the server.  b00_breeze.dataService.webApi  does seem pretty easy to understand so I should be able work it out from there. Thanks guys.

Comment: Excellent. FWIW, we did the same thing when we wrote the server-side save handling for our [node-sequelize implementation](http://www.getbreezenow.com/sequelize-mysqlpostgressql-lite)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for this is buried in the [DataServiceAdapters](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/dataserviceadapters) page.  Look about halfway down, under the heading **saveChanges (saveContext, saveBundle) -> promise**.

There's an example of what the JSON looks like in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440285/how-to-implement-savechanges-with-breeze-js-and-nancy/28447717#28447717).

Comment: The DataServiceAdapters page does not really describe the SaveBundle that I can see. e.g. What are the properties of an Entity Aspect? What do these properties contain? What goes in the originalValuesMap? Does every entity always have an Entity Aspect? etc. I can kind of work it out from looking at the HTTP post body in Fiddler but this does not seem like the best way to go about it.

Comment: Good point; the DataServiceAdapters page should link to the [API docs describing EntityAspect](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityAspect.html).  Every entity sent by the Breeze client will have an EntityAspect.  The EntityAspect is important, because it tells the server what type of entity it is, and the state of the entity compared to the server (added/modified/deleted).

Comment: The [originalValues](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityAspect.html#property_originalValues) map is populated if the entity is modified; it keeps a copy of the original value of each changed property.

Comment: Actually, the `EntityAspect` property of an entry in the `SaveBundle` is NOT the same as the `EntityAspect` on the JavaScript entity. Not even close. But it does contain information you need to make sense of an item such as the name of the `EntityType`, the string name of its entity state, and the `originalValuesMap`.

Comment: Please see my answer for a better understanding of this issue.